# SIGINT not propagating to child processes

Tags: bash

I have the following 2 scripts.

`script1.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -x
set -e

./script2.sh &
pid=$!

max_retry=15
counter=0
until curl --silent --head --fail localhost:8000; do
  if ! jobs %1; then
    echo "Server quit unexpectedly before reporting successful status"
    exit 1
  fi
  if [[ $counter -eq $max_retry ]]; then
    echo "Server never reported healthy status"
    kill -INT $pid
    wait $pid
    exit 1
  fi
  echo "Server not ready. Sleeping for 1 second"
  sleep 1
  counter=$((counter + 1))
done
echo "Server responded healthy"
kill -INT $pid
wait $pid
echo "Done"
```

`script2.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -x
set -e

docker run \
  -p 8000:80 \
  nginxdemos/hello
```

When I run `./script1.sh`, I expect the script to execute `script2.sh` in the background, run `curl` until it succeeds, and then terminate `script2.sh` with `SIGINT`. However, that does not happen. The `kill` on line 26 does not terminate the script. Instead, `script2.sh` continues to run, until I press `Ctrl` + `C`.

Why does this happen, and how do I get `script2.sh` to properly terminate and propagate the `SIGINT` signal to any child processes?

Comment: Not sure why you want to use SIGINT, but that’s fine. Set up a bash signal handler for it. Use that to debug (echo) and propagate signals down to curl. Use “jobs” to verify the child is in the expected process group. Docker may catch signals, so substitute a simpler command during testing.

Answer (score 0):

From the low-level OS point of view, the right way to do this is to pass a negative value for the PID to `kill`, specifying the process group ID (PGID).

Unfortunately, it will usually be the case that the process you want to kill by group ID is in the same group as the parent process that wants to kill it. The entire group will terminate, though, including the parent.

This is a Stupid Unix problem which you can only resolve with hacks.

I have a `script1.sh` which backgrounds `script2.sh`, similarly to yours. Instead of a `docker` command, I just have a `sleep 3600` command in `script2.sh`. If I just kill `script2.sh`, the `sleep 3600` stays alive.

`script2.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
sleep 3600
```

In `script1.sh`, I use an Awk program to find all the descendants of the `script2.sh` process.

`script1.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

./script2.sh &
pid=$!

sleep 1

descendants=$(awk -f descendants.awk $pid)

kill -TERM $pid

for desc in $descendants; do
  kill -TERM $desc
done

# wait for script2.sh by pid
wait $pid

echo done
```

Here is my `descentants.awk`:

```
BEGIN {
  # symbolic names for "ps -efj" columns
  PID=2
  PPID=3

  root_process = ARGV[1]

  while (("ps -efj" | getline) > 0)
    parent[$PID] = $PPID

  for (child in parent) {
    pid = child;

    do {
      par = parent[pid]
      if (par == root_process) {
        print child
        break
      }
      pid = par
    } while (par != 0 && par != 1)
  }
}
```

This works by building an association hash based on columns 2 and 3 of the `ps -efj` output: the hash gives us the parent for any given PID in the system. We then walk all the pids. For every pid, we trace its ancestry by walking the chain of parentage. We print every pid which has the given pid as a direct or indirect ancestor.

This will not find descendants whose parents died and which were therefore reparented to PID 1 (before our Awk script gathered the parentage data).

Like if `script2.sh` were to put `sleep 3600 &` into the background and then exit, the Awk script would come up empty; the `sleep` would keep running, but have 1 as its PPID.

In other words, we assume that the script and its descendants are well behaved. If anything dies voluntarily, it does so cleanly and takes care not to leave descendants. If we kill it abruptly, we take care of the descendants.

---

P.S. I'm working on a GNU Linux. I did some testing of this Awk script by comparing the output to what is seen in `pstree -Tp`.  `-T` means to hide threads. That's another thing we don't do; we don't go into threads. We assume that if we kill a process, its threads will be taken care of by the threading library. Threads actually being processes in a Linux thing.

Example: here is a slice of `pstree -Tp` output:

```
           │               ├─firefox(22690)─┬─Isolated Web Co(22776)
           │               │                ├─Isolated Web Co(22880)
           │               │                ├─Privileged Cont(22870)
           │               │                ├─Socket Process(22748)
           │               │                ├─Web Content(22907)
           │               │                ├─Web Content(22934)
           │               │                ├─Web Content(27810)
           │               │                └─WebExtensions(22820)
```

And here is the script's output:

```
$ awk -f descendants.awk 22690
22820
22880
22907
22776
22870
22934
27810
22748
```

It found the same eight processes. Another example with a subtree deeper than 1:

```
           │               ├─gnome-terminal-(6802)───bash(6814)─┬─git(365)───wish(368)─┬─aspell(382)
           │               │                                    │                      └─git-diff-index(15474)
           │               │                                    ├─git(26636)───wish(26641)───aspell(26650)
           │               │                                    ├─txr(15717)
           │               │                                    └─vi(933)
```

```
$ awk -f descendants.awk 6802
365
26641
368
382
15474
26636
26650
933
15717
6814
```